# post data from one page to another on button click using java script

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form name="payform" action="payment.html" method="POST">
  Amount: <input type="text" id="amount">
  <button id="buttonPay" type="submit" onclick="someFunction()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I need to post the text box content along with some variables which are defined outside of the form.

Comment: Add more code or description

Comment: Are you using angular or not? just change the button type to submit, and your variables will be posted to payment.html

Comment: If you just change your button to <input type='submit'../> the browser will post the form data to payment.html

Comment: then it will post the contents inside the <form> tag right? i want to post some more data which is defined outside the form tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass any data with a form submit you could add an input hidden tag inside your form (it has to be inside the form tag):

```
<input type="hidden" name="varKey" value="varVal" />
```

If the data lies outside the form tag for some reason, use jQuery to get the data and update the hidden tag's value

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
$out_side_var = "myData";
?>

<form name="payform" action="payment.html" method="POST">
Amount: <input type="text" id="amount">
<input type="hidden" name="myData" id="myData" value='<?php echo $out_side_var ?>'> 
<button id="buttonPay" type="button" onclick="someFunction()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i am not using php

Comment: what type of variable you pass, out side of the form?

Comment: some json responses.